# Retrofit illegalargumentexception, no annotation found

Tags: android, retrofit, android-proguard

So when running my app I'm getting this  error:

```
06-17 12:56:08.547 E/AndroidRuntime(23432): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: XapoService.credit: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
```

I have Google searches and found it may be caused by ProGuard. I added the following lines to my ProGuard:

```
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.inject.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.james.mime4j.** { *; }
-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class java.io.** { *; }
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep interface retrofit.** { *; }
-dontwarn rx.**
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
@retrofit.http.* <methods>
}
    -keep class com.google.common.** { *; }
    -keep class com.mycompany.testSDK.XapoService { ; }
```

Yet I am still receiving the error at this call:

```
import retrofit.client.Response;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Query;
import java.util.List;



public interface XapoService {
    @GET("/credit/")
    Response credit(@Query("appID") String appID, @Query("hash") String hash);
}
```

Comment: If you don't run proguard, do you still get the crash?

Comment: possibly you missed a coma after `<methods>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK was updated today for Android. Solved.