# Retrofit 2 no annotation found

Tags: android, firebase, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying get specific data from Firebase. Using REST API and Retrofit 2 on client side.

Here is my JSON structure on Firebase:

```
{
"profiles" : {
"-KAG0XPBVNNF_RT55lwV" : {
  "GCMTocken" : "rtdjhsrfjt546456",
  "firstName" : "P",
  "gender" : 1,
  "lastName" : "Strongman",
  "likes" : 0,
  "nickname" : "drake1",
  "uid" : "facebook:957484"
}
}
}
```

Request interface:

```
@GET("/profiles.json")
Observable<Profile> getProfile(@Query("orderBy") String key, @Query("equalTo") String uid);
```

On this request i always get:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1) 
for method FirebaseAPI.getProfile
```

**EDIT**

i need this request:

```
https://incandescent-torch-4.firebaseio.com/profiles.json?orderBy="uid"&equalTo="facebook:95748485767896"
```

My retrofit setup:

```
String BASE_FIREBASE_URL = "https://incandescent-torch-4.firebaseio.com";

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_FIREBASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    restAPI = retrofit.create(FirebaseAPI.class);
```

Request from RxJava:

```
RestFirebaseClient.getInstance().getProfile(authData.getUid())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Profile>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNext(Profile profile) {

                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
I observe in your code request @GET request just put "/" & make sure in you url you have to remove "/" at the end of url like - 
like this - 

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://incandescent-torch-4.firebaseio.com")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

@GET("/profiles.json")
Observable<Profile> getProfile(@Query("orderBy") String key, @Query("equalTo") String uid);
```

This is included in [documentation](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) of retrofit.

Comment: Just did like you said but doesn't help. Please look at my edit

Comment: your url response is -  {  "error" : "404 Not Found"}

Comment: sorry i can't give you access to my firebase but i checked request in postman, works well

Comment: No problem, I found those modifications. can you share stack strace

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103275/discussion-between-ajinkya-and-drake).

Answer (score 0):

Add Retrofit 2 dependency to Gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.0.0-RC1'
```

Initialize Retrofit:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                        .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                .addInterceptor(new TokenInterceptor())
                .addInterceptor(new AuthenticationInterceptor())
                .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://your_url/")
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Create Retrofit services, such as:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface ProfileService {

    @GET("profile")
    Call<User> get();
}
```

I used `@GET("profile")` and finally url was: `http://your_url/profile`

You maybe try change `Observable<Profile>` to `Call<Profile>` and delete `.json` from `@GET("profiles.json")`

Comment: i know how setup retrofit. I think my problem is not is this

Comment: Maybe it's will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898350/retrofit-illegalargumentexception-no-annotation-found?rq=1